# Using IIS smtp for incoming and outgoing and use hMailserver for mail accounts

Tags: iis, smtp, pop3, email-server

I have installed `hMailServer` in one machine and `IIS STMP` in another machine. Even though `hMailSever` itself is a SMTP server.

I can't avoid this because the `IIS SMTP` server has some hooks which which encrypts and decrypts the incoming and outgoing mails.

Since `IIS SMTP` doesn't support to create & manage mail accounts, I thought of using `hMail Server`. Now I am able to send the outgoing mails by setting the SMTP relay settings in `hMailServer`. In this way If I send a mail to `hMailServer`'s SMTP it relays to `IIS SMTP` server. This works fine.

But If I receive a mail from outside the mail directly goes to `hMailServer`. But the mails are encrypted. Ideally I should receive all mails to `IIS SMTP` then decrypt and send it to `hMailServer` so that the user can download the mails through POP3 to his outlook.

How do I do this please? Is there a option to transfer all incoming mails from `IIS SMTP` to send it to `hMailServer`. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS SMTP Virtual Server (using IIS6 Manager)
2. Right Click -> Properties
3. Delivery Tab
4. Advanced
5. Fill in "Smart Host" (your hMailServer)

More details [here](http://fmuntean.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-forward-emails-using-a-gmail-account/)